# Laravel Class 'App\FBLogin\authlogin' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I created a new `FBLogin.php` file in `App` Folder, added class:

```
namespace App\FBLogin;
class authlogin {}
```

Now i want to use this class in my Controller File, so i added:

```
use App\FBLogin\authlogin;
```

Now when i am trying to use this class `authlogin`, it is showing me error `Class 'App\FBLogin\authlogin' not found`

Is there something i am doing wrong?
Laravel Version: 5.5

Comment: Run `composer du` command.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a lowercase format when naming your classes? Anyway, your namespace inside your app folder should follow your file structure.

If you create your class like below,

```
namespace App\FBLogin;

class authlogin {
    // code here
}
```

Your file structure must be:

```
app/
    FBLogin/
        authlogin.php
```

Then you can use the class anywhere in your app by declaring the proper namespace

```
use App\FBLogin\authlogin;

$authlogin = new authlogin();
```

Comment: glad to hear hehe